# Web Chat No Sign in Box Displayed

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to run the following code https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AadV2Bot

to test out authentication. The code works in the emulator, I see a sign in box and can complete the flow. When I access the bot via web chat all I see is this message "[File of type 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth']"

Is there some setting that I need to enable to show the box ?

Comment: I can reproduce [same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbCnb.png) with webchat, it seems that the card is sent as [an attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q5Yz.png) with `"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth"`, which does not render well in webchat, if possible, you can [create a github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) to report it.

Comment: We are investigating this issue, we are tracking it in our [github repository in this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4632)

Comment: @JasonSowers:  This is an open issue since May. Any update on ETA?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using old version of emulator. Try using the new one 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases

Comment: I am using the newest emulator and it does work there. It doesn't work in the browser and I have tried chrome and edge

Comment: @sunilsingh any luck? Did you find a solution. Facing the same issue. Working fine on emulator but not on website